# Trying to change resolution for LG ULTRAWIDE monitor

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution, lg

I am running Ubuntu 16.04LTS with the AMD RV620 Graphics card which has display port.  I am trying to connect LG Monitor with resolution 2560 x 1080 60Hz Frequency.  I have connected my monitor which only has HDMI input through DispalyPost to HDMI Video adapter Converter.  The maximum resolution I can select from Display is 1920 x 1080.

My xrandr output is:

```
$ xrandr -q

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 673mm x 284mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

I tried to add my desired resolution (2560 x 1080) with these commands:

```
$ gtf 2560 1080 60

  # 2560x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 230.76 MHz
  Modeline "2560x1080_60.00"  230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync 

$ xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-1 "2560x1080_60.00"
```

Everything works up until now...but when I try to do this:

```
$ xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --mode "2560x1080_60.00"
```

My display loses signal and goes blank (I see `No signal. Entering in power saving mode` - message)

I have to hard re-boot to start the system again.

Please advise if I need to install any specific drive.  I only have the default driver that came with 16.04, here is my system info:

[image: system info]

Comment: Please edit your post to please use code markup  `{}` for commands and log snippets, it makes it easier to read, thanks.